# Python import MySQLdb, Apache Internal Server Error

Tags: python, cgi

I'm having a similar problem to that described in "[.cgi problem with web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621874/cgi-problem-with-web-server)", although I reviewed and tested the previously suggested solutions without success.

I'm running the same program on Mac OS X 10.5.8, Apache 2.2.13, using Python 2.6.4.  I can successfully run the code in the python shell and the terminal command-line, but I get `<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named MySQLdb` when I try to run it at "http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.cgi".  It successfully runs if I comment out `import MySQLdb`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgitb
cgitb.enable() 
import MySQLdb

print "Content-Type: text/html"
print
print "<html><head><title>Books</title></head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h1>Books</h1>"
print "<ul>"

connection = MySQLdb.connect(user='me', passwd='letmein', db='my_db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM books ORDER BY pub_date DESC LIMIT 10")

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print "<li>%s</li>" % row[0]

print "</ul>"
print "</body></html>"

connection.close()
```

---

**[edit]** Based on the first answer:

If I modify `test.cgi` as specified and run it from the terminal command-line, the directory of `MySQLdb` is shown in `sys.path`.  However, when I run it via the web server, I get the same error.  If I comment out `import MySQLdb` in `test.cgi` with the new for-loop, the page fails to open.

How do I set Apache's PYTHONPATH?  At the python shell, I tried:

```
import MySQLdb
import os
print os.path.dirname(MySQLdb.__file__)
```

Then, based on other posts, I tried to add the resultant path in the original `test.cgi`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.0.0/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-macosx-10.5-i386.egg/')
```

but this produced the same error.

---

**[edit]**

Unfortunately, neither solution worked.  Adding the path to `sys.path` gave me the same error as before.  Hard-coding the path to the python binary `#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python` produced a lengthy error, part of which is shown:

```
A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.

 /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/test.cgi in ()
   15 #sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.0.0/lib/python2.6/site-packages/')
   16 
   17 import MySQLdb
   18 #import _mysql
   19 
MySQLdb undefined
 /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py in ()
 /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/_mysql.py in ()
 /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/_mysql.py in __bootstrap__()
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.0.0/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py in resource_filename(self=<pkg_resources.ResourceManager instance at 0x3c8a80>, package_or_requirement='_mysql', resource_name='_mysql.so')
  848         """Return a true filesystem path for specified resource"""
  849         return get_provider(package_or_requirement).get_resource_filename(
  850             self, resource_name
  851         )
  852 
self = <pkg_resources.ResourceManager instance at 0x3c8a80>, resource_name = '_mysql.so'

...

<class 'pkg_resources.ExtractionError'>: Can't extract file(s) to egg cache The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg cache: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/WebServer/.python-eggs' The Python egg cache directory is currently set to: /Library/WebServer/.python-eggs Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory? You can change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable to point to an accessible directory. 
      args = ("Can't extract file(s) to egg cache\n\nThe followin...nt\nvariable to point to an accessible directory.\n",) 
      cache_path = '/Library/WebServer/.python-eggs' 
      manager = <pkg_resources.ResourceManager instance at 0x3c8a80> 
      message = "Can't extract file(s) to egg cache\n\nThe followin...nt\nvariable to point to an accessible directory.\n" 
      original_error = OSError(13, 'Permission denied')
```

This error seems to imply that it may have something to do with setting PYTHON_EGG_CACHE and/or permissions...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the python binary that Apache is using has `MySQLdb` in its `PYTHONPATH`.

Confirm it by checking the location of MySQLdb in the working script:

```
import os
print os.path.dirname(MySQLdb.__file__)
```

And comparing that to the output of `sys.path` inside of `test.cgi`:

```
import sys
for p in sys.path: 
    print p + "<br/>"
```

If the directory of `MySQLdb` from the working scripting is not in `sys.path` on the broken script, there is your problem.

**Edit:**

Based on the update to the OP, it looks like the directory that you need to add to your `PYTHONPATH` is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.0.0/lib/python2.6/site-packages/`.  The other path you used:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.0.0/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-macosx-10.5-i386.egg/
```

... is the location of the .egg that was installed.  I hate .egg installs for this reason because it can be confusing, especially to people who are relatively new to Python.

The other option is to hard-code the path to the Python binary in your `test.cgi` to the same one you have confirmed you are using from the command-line.  In your script you have `/usr/bin/env python`, which is a good practice. However, when you're running into environment and path problems like you are, it might be a good idea to hard-code the python binary until you can get past this hurdle.

From the command-line perform a `which python`, to determine which python binary the CLI is referencing:

```
% which python
/opt/local/bin/python
```

The path to my python binary is `/opt/local/bin/python`. So if that were yours, replace `/usr/bin/env python` with that in `test.cgi`:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python
import cgitb
# ... and so on ...
```

After doing that, are you still receiving the `ImportError`?  If so, you've narrowed down the problem.  Adding `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.0.0/lib/python2.6/site-packages/` to `sys.path` may solve your problem without having to hard-code the path to the python binary.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too, but I figured it out after several hours trying.

**Here is my scenario:** I need to `import MySQLdb` in a Python cgi file, but it failed, and raised the `ImportError`.

Then I print out the Web server path and local python path, they were:

**Web Server path**

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
```

**`/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`**

and Python path:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.25-py2.7.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydelicious-0.6-py2.7.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/feedparser-5.1.2-py2.7.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googlemaps-1.0.2-py2.7.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-intel.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elementtree-1.2.7_20070827_preview-py2.7.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2-1.5.170-py2.7.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.7.4-py2.7.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson-2.1.6-py2.7-macosx-10.5-intel.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_twitter-0.8.3-py2.7.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyfb-0.4.1-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/wxPython-ansi-2.8.12.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/wxPython-ansi-2.8.12.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-ansi
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL
/usr/local/lib/wxPython-ansi-2.8.12.1/lib/python2.7
```

**`/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`**

They both have the path `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`, obviously, this is a path for installing third-party packages, but it is empty.

Why?

I can run Python script very well on local python environment with additional packages, then I noticed that all those packages were installed at

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

When I run cgi file on web server, the above path can not be found by the server, and of course `import MySQLdb` failed.

What I did here is to copy the files in

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/"
```

to

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

To test which version of Python that Apache was using, I added the following code:

```
import sys
version = sys.version
path = sys.path

...

print "<h1>%s</h1>" % version                                                                  
print "<h1>%s</h1>" % path
```

which indicated that Apache was indeed using the manufacturer-installed Python 2.5.1, and not Python 2.6.4 with the associated MySQLdb module.  Thus, adding the following code to the original `test.cgi` fixed the problem:

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp'
import sys
sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.0.0/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-macosx-10.5-i386.egg')
```

There is possibly a systematic fix by altering the PYTHONPATH in APACHE's httpd.conf, but I haven't yet figured it out.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2232542/4) to the question [Python import MySQLdb, Apache Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232542/python-import-mysqldb-apache-internal-server-error) by the OP [bernie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/269836/bernie) under CC BY-SA 2.5.</sub>