# Python script Import error while running through apache server

Tags: python, gstreamer, pygst

I have a problem. I am using a python script that uses pygst library. I have no problem executing the script manually through command line. I also tried switching the user to _www and executing script (since a few path to a few libraries might not be set) but it seems to work fine... The problem is that i am not able to reproduce the error manually. I know i am missing something small.

```
File "/••••••.py", line 2, in <module>
    import os, sys, pygst
ImportError: No module named pygst
```

**edit
The call to the script is made through php script ?? could this be the problem ?

Comment: Do any answers in something like *[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232542/python-import-mysqldb-apache-internal-server-error?rq=1)* help?

Comment: @summea thanks for the link ... my config was messed .. but i do hope they find a cleaner way to deal with PYTHONPATH .. :)